# Why cannot create MySql view with "merge" algorithm when using constructs such as "group by"?

Tags: mysql, database, view, group-by

There is a strange rule in MySql which basically says if you want to create a view and you want to use constructs such as `GROUP BY, DISTINCT, UNION`, etc. in your view, you cannot create your view with `ALGORITHM = MERGE`! Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html).

This basically means that if you create a view in MySql and you have something like GROUP BY in your view, if you run a query like:

```
select * from MyView
where foo = 2
```

then MySql will read all the rows from MyView and put it in a temp table and after that it will apply the where clause (foo = 2) to the temp table and return you the result.

The problem is that if your view has 10 Million rows it will get all the 10M rows and then apply the where clause, which is insanely inefficient.

So, does anyone know what is the rationale behind this? I know that MS Sql Server is not doing this and I bet Oracle is not doing it either.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked [on the MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,56681,56681) about union views, years ago. A MySQL developer agreed that it should be easy to implement the `MERGE` algorithm on views using `UNION`, but AFAIK it still has not been implemented!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just don't understand why MySQL team do not implement such a trivial and important feature.

Comment: Agreed, it sucks! :-/