# improve mysql query with view

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I want to calculate the net amount of goods i have in each location. This involves 2 tables : **stocks** and **locations**. And 4 views derived from table stocks : **view_cr**, **view_dr**, **view_union_crdr**, **view_net_stocks**.

The **indexes** on table stocks : id, code,type, dr_coloumn, id-code-type.
The **indexes** on table locations : id_locations, type, id_locations-type.

The views are :

view_cr :

`SELECT cr_coloumn AS TOTAL FROM stocks`

view_dr :

`SELECT (0-dr_coloumn) AS TOTAL FROM stocks WHERE dr_coloumn > 0`

view_union_crdr :

`SELECT * FROM view_cr UNION SELECT * FROM view_dr`

view_net_stocks :

```
SELECT  SUM(TOTAL), type, code, id
    FROM  view_union_crdr VUCRDR
    JOIN  locations LOC
               ON (LOC.id   = VUCRDR.id
              AND  LOC.type = VUCRDR.type )
    GROUP BY  VUCRDR.code, VUCRDR.id, VUCRDR.type`
```

Whenever i do SELECT * FROM view_net_stocks, it takes more than 20 seconds. I feel it is still to slow... The number of records from stocks are only 65400 records.

How can i improve the query ?

thanks

(from comment)

```
CREATE
    ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@%`
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    VIEW tsj_stock_opname3 AS 
select  sum(vij.total) AS mytotal, vij.tsj_ml_id AS tsj_ml_id,
        vij.tsj_mi_name AS tsj_mi_name, vij.tsj_mi_code AS tsj_mi_code,
        vij.tsj_ml_type AS tsj_ml_type, b.ml_name AS ml_name
    from  (union_cr_dr2 vij
            join  v_locations2 b on(((vij.tsj_ml_id = b.ml_id)
                              and  (vij.tsj_ml_type = b.ml_type)))
          )
    group by  vij.tsj_mi_code, vij.tsj_ml_id, vij.`tsj_ml_type``
```

Comment: the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html states View processing is not optimized:

It is not possible to create an index on a view.

Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm. However, a view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables (although indexes can be used during generation of the temporary tables). What algorithm does Show create view <viewname> show?

Comment: `CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `tsj_stock_opname3` AS select sum(`vij`.`total`) AS `mytotal`,`vij`.`tsj_ml_id` AS `tsj_ml_id`,`vij`.`tsj_mi_name` AS `tsj_mi_name`,`vij`.`tsj_mi_code` AS `tsj_mi_code`,`vij`.`tsj_ml_type` AS `tsj_ml_type`,`b`.`ml_name` AS `ml_name` from (`union_cr_dr2` `vij` join `v_locations2` `b` on(((`vij`.`tsj_ml_id` = `b`.`ml_id`) and (`vij`.`tsj_ml_type` = `b`.`ml_type`)))) group by `vij`.`tsj_mi_code`,`vij`.`tsj_ml_id`,`vij`.`tsj_ml_type``

Comment: Try changing the algorithm to merge and see if that helps. it may not For UNDEFINED, MySQL chooses which algorithm to use. It prefers MERGE over TEMPTABLE if possible, because MERGE is usually more efficient and because a view cannot be updatable if a temporary table is used.

Comment: Wow.. yes, it improves drastically by using MERGE algorithm. Now it runs 0.021 seconds. Thanks man..

Comment: @padjee pl. submit as an answer

Comment: BUT.. when i run "SHOW CREATE VIEW union_cr_dr2", it returns back to "CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED..." Why ? And why the query is still fast ?

Comment: "Try changing the algorithm to merge and see if that helps. it may not For UNDEFINED, MySQL chooses which algorithm to use. It prefers MERGE over TEMPTABLE if possible, because MERGE is usually more efficient and because a view cannot be updatable if a temporary table is used." >>> I think that This is the answer to my question... BTW, i can't see any button / check box to accept the answer...

Comment: Bottom Line:  `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar, and sometimes lead to slower queries than if not using them.

Comment: Why use `Locations` in `JOIN  locations LOC`?  There don't seem to be any columns in the `VIEW` that matter.

Answer (score 0):

the manual dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html states *View processing is not optimized: It is not possible to create an index on a view. Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm. However, a view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables (although indexes can be used during generation of the temporary tables).* 
AND 
*For UNDEFINED, MySQL chooses which algorithm to use. It prefers MERGE over TEMPTABLE if possible, because MERGE is usually more efficient and because a view cannot be updatable if a temporary table is used.*
Try explicitly setting the algorithm when creating the view.

Comment: How to explicitly set the algorithm to MERGE ? What i did was running ''Create Algorithm=Merge. . . '' when creating the view.

Comment: I found this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949038/why-cannot-create-mysql-view-with-merge-algorithm-when-using-constructs-such-a . It says that MERGE cant be used with GROUP BY.